# Splitting date time column in excel vba to two separate columns gives different results depending on whether dd part is greater than 12 or no

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code:

```
Sub SplitDateTime()
Dim dDate As Date
Dim dTime As Date
Dim x As Integer

MsgBox "Split Date Time"

For x = 2 To 21
    'Sets the date in the cell of the first column
    dDate = Cells(x, 2)
    dTime = Cells(x, 2)
    Cells(x, 2).Value = Format(dDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")

    'Sets the time in the cell of the second column
    Cells(x, 3).Value = Format(dTime, "hh:mm")
Next x
```

When this is run I get the following:

[image: excel table]

Notice that the 2nd to the 6th row of dates weren't converted properly. It seems that these rows were changed to mm/dd/yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyyy (they were originally 12/01/2019...), possibly because the conversion is inconsistent, and then the time was inserted as 00:00. Has anyone any suggestions on how to correct this?

This is the original:

[image: Original columns, the first column was subsequently deleted]

Original columns, the first column was subsequently deleted

Comment: No way to tell what the original data is, so no way to tell why the format is used. Post the underlying data.

Comment: If your Windows Regional settings are MDY, your results are expected.

Comment: This is the original:

Comment: My regional settings are dd/mm/yyyy for the short date and dd MMMM yyyy for the long date

Comment: Hmm VBA is sometimes US-centric with regard to dates.  Try the answer I posted.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks very much, that worked fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
Sub SplitDateTime()
Dim dDate As Date
Dim dTime As Date
Dim x As Integer

MsgBox "Split Date Time"
For x = 2 To 21
    'Sets the date in the cell of the first column
    dDate = Cells(x, 2)
    With Cells(x, 2)
        .Value = Int(dDate)
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
    End With

    'Sets the time in the cell of the second column
    With Cells(x, 3)
        .Value = dDate - Int(dDate)
        .NumberFormat = "hh:mm"
    End With
Next x
End Sub
```